# Sorting a `List<object>` by object properties

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, object, ienumerable

I have some different objects that all of them have a integer field called `Place`. Is there a way to sort out this list without knowing what is the actual object? I mean just accessing the `Place` field and sort the list based on this number. possibly using linq or something?

some example objects:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Place;
    //Other related fields
}

public class Human
{
    public int Place;
    //Other related fields
}

//Somwhere in program
List<object> GameObjects;
```

Comment: You can do it with [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx). Is there a reason why you're not using some common base object / interface?

Comment: Both Human and Car should derive (directly or indirectly) from WorldObject or something, which has the Place property. Another option is to have them both implement the IHavePlace interface. The list should then be of WorldObject or of IHavePlace type.

Comment: You can create parent class for them or interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should derive your classes from a base class.

```
public class Base
{
    public int Place;
}

public class Car : Base
{
    // other properties
}

public class Human : Base
{
    // other properties
}
```

Then you can create a list of your base type, add humans
and cars. After that you can use the Linq `Sort` or `OrderBy` method.

```
List<Base> list = new List<Base>();
list.Add(new Human { Place = 2 });
list.Add(new Car { Place = 1 });

var sortedList = list.Sort(x => x.Place);
```

#### More Information

- [The C# Station Tutorial - Lesson 8: Class Inheritance](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson08)
- [MSDN - Queryable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264.aspx)
- [MSDN - List.Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)

Comment: Add the fact that the list is then of type Base, and your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

No because `object` doesn't have a `Place` property only `Car`/`Human` do.

There are a couple of ways you can solve this problem:

**Introduce a base class**

```
public class GameObject
{
    public int Place { get; set; }
}

public class Car : GameObject
{}

public class Human : GameObject
{}

...
List<GameObject> GameObjects
```

**Use a generic interface**

```
public interface IGameObject
{
    int Place { get; }
}

public class Car : IGameObject
{
    public int Place { get; set; }
}

public class Human : IGameObject
{
    public int Place { get; set; }
}

List<IGameObject> GameObjects
```

Answer (score 1):

What you just discovered is relationship between those types. Both `Car` and `Human` seem to have a Place property, so you should extract an interface à la `IGameObject`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use an interface. If you can't, you still can do late binding using the `dynamic` keyword:

```
        var list = new List<object>
        {
            new Car { Place = 3 },
            new Human { Place = 1 },
            new Car { Place = 2 }
        };

        var sortedList = list.OrderBy(o => ((dynamic)o).Place);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible using delegate methods with reflection. This is upto my knowledge, may be some other giants create it without using reflection

Answer (score 0):

You could let them implement an interface `IPlaceable` and use a property instead of only a field:

```
public interface IPlaceable
{
    int Place { get; set; }
}

public class Car : IPlaceable
{
    public int Place { get; set; }
    //Other related fields
}

public class Human : IPlaceable
{
    public int Place { get; set; }
    //Other related fields
}


// Somwhere in program
List<IPlaceable> GameObjects;

// Somwhere else
GameObjects.OrderBy(go => go.Place);
```

Note that the list now is a `List<IPlaceable>` instead of a `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is use an Interface, like this:

```
public Interface IFoo
{
  int place;
}
```

And the implement that interface:

```
public class Car : IFoo
{
    public int Place;
}

public class Human : IFoo
{
    public int Place;
}
```

And then with linq:

```
List<IFoo> GameObjects;

GameObjects.OrderBy(g => g.Place);
```